# How to change the colors of pylab legend?

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphics, matplotlib

How to change colors of the different legends of a graph? I need to do this in the same line of the "pylab.legend", by my own code issues...

For example:

```
pylab.legend (("Legend1", "Legend2")) #and more legends....
```

How do I set on the same line, Legend1 with red color and blue in Legend2? I've been testing this:

```
pylab.legend (("Legend1", 'r', "Legend2 ',' b '))
```

But doesn't work

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/legend_auto.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the color of the legend line? I think it makes no sense. If you do so, how can you tell which one is which?

To change the color of text, such that the color of text matches the color of the corresponding line:

```
plt.plot(range(10), 'r', label='L1')
plt.plot(range(1,11), 'b', label='L2')
L=plt.legend(loc=0)
_=[item.set_color(jtem.get_color()) for item, jtem in zip(L.get_texts(), L.get_children()[1:])]
```

[image]

If you want to change them both, say to `['red', 'blue']`:

```
_=[(item.set_color(c), jtem.set_color(c))
   for item, jtem, c in zip(L.get_texts(), L.get_children()[1:], ['red', 'blue'])]
```

Comment: because I need to do: pl.legend("L1"(my color), "L2"(my another color)). In that way I know which one is which.

Comment: the plot is done with semilogy in another function (before in the execution), I just need to configure labels an colors in this section of my code. Thats my question.